# Trying to make a data module

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a data module in JavaScript, but can't access the data from outside, while everything works fine when I try to log it from inside

```
'use strict;'

function manager() {
  let data = {};

  function define(name, surname, age) {
    let length = Object.keys(data).length;
    data[`user${length + 1}`] = {
      name: name,
      surname: surname,
      age: age
    };
  }

  function get(num) {
    return data[`user${num}`];
  }

  return {
    define: define,
    get: get
  };
};


manager().define('John', 'Smith', 17);
console.log(manager().get(1));


//undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call `manager` you define a new variable named `data` and assign it the value `{}`.

So `manager().define('John', 'Smith', 17);` creates an object, assigns some data to it, then the object drops out of scope and is garbage collected.

Then `console.log(manager().get(1));` creates a new object, and it has no data in it.

Define the variable and assign the object to it *outside* the function.

Comment: I see. But is there any way to make the object private?

Comment: @IlyaKozel i have posted the answer above to make data object as private. You can check it over there.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use module pattern and the execution will like this

```
var manager = (function() {
    'use strict';
    let data = {};

    function define(name, surname, age) {
        let length = Object.keys(data).length;
        data[`user${length + 1}`] = {
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            age: age
        };
    }

    function get(num) {
        return data[`user${num}`];
    }
    return {
        define: define,
        get: get
    };
}());

manager.define('John', 'Smith', 17)
console.log(manager.get(1))
```

```js
var manager = (function() {
    'use strict';
    let data = {};

    function define(name, surname, age) {
        let length = Object.keys(data).length;
        data[`user${length + 1}`] = {
            name: name,
            surname: surname,
            age: age
        };
    }

    function get(num) {
        return data[`user${num}`];
    }
    return {
        define: define,
        get: get
    };
}());

manager.define('John', 'Smith', 17)
console.log(manager.get(1))
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I want this to work, thank you very much!